# gettext.translation returns None

Tags: python, gettext

I have the following lines of code. It seems gettext.translation returns None. In fact, when I use locale as it-IT, it returns strings without translation.

[image]

Comment: can you please post the whole program you've worked on? The posted code doesn't seem clear to understand the scope of it.

Comment: locale = handler_input.request_envelope.request.locale 
i18n = gettext.translation('data', localedir='locales', languages=[locale], fallback=True) 
handler_input.attributes_manager.request_attributes["_"] = i18n.gettext 

handler_input.attributes_manager.request_attributes["_"] 
speak_output = _(data.WELCOME_MESSAGE)

speak_output contains string in english but locale is it-IT.
data is python file with strings